# How append the username into the file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, filenames

I have this script,

```
find -iname \*.${EXT} -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l --time-style="+%b %Y" | awk '{print $NF,$3,$5,$6,$7}' OFS="\t" > ${EXT}.txt
awk -vextension="${EXT}" -vfiletype="${TYPE}" -vcompress="${COMP}" -vOFS="\t" '{print $0, ext, filetype, compress}' < ${EXT}.txt >> all.txt
```

I would like alter the script to automatically append the username of user that ran this script into the file e.g. “Jason_all.txt” as final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple :

```
find -iname \*.${EXT} -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l --time-style="+%b %Y" | awk '{print $NF,$3,$5,$6,$7}' OFS="\t" > ${EXT}.txt
awk -vextension="${EXT}" -vfiletype="${TYPE}" -vcompress="${COMP}" -vOFS="\t" '{print $0, ext, filetype, compress}' < ${EXT}.txt >> "${USER}_all.txt"
```

Better edit this snippet to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Check `man find | less +/'printf format'` instead